# Add dynamically function to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to add some JavaScript function to Chart.js. I want to add them outside the `Options` because I want to find a way to add them dynamically when I need them in my [Blazor](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorChartjs) project.

So, I have this JavaScript code where I create a graph.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133],
        label: "Total",
        borderColor: "rgb(62,149,205)",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(62,149,205,0.1)"
      },
      {
        data: [70, 90, 44, 60, 83, 90, 100],
        label: "Accepted",
        borderColor: "rgb(60,186,159)",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(60,186,159,0.1)"
      },
      {
        data: [10, 21, 60, 44, 17, 21, 17],
        label: "Pending",
        borderColor: "rgb(255,165,0)",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255,165,0,0.1)"
      },
      {
        data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 0, 16],
        label: "Rejected",
        borderColor: "rgb(196,88,80)",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(196,88,80,0.1)"
      }
    ]
  }
});

myChart.data.labels.push('June');

myChart.options.plugins.legend.onClick = function (e, legendItem, legend) {
  console.log('legend click');
  console.log(legendItem);
};

myChart.options.elements.line.backgroundColor = function (ctx) {
  console.log('line backgroundColor');
  return '#000000';
};

myChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="150"></canvas>
```

At the end of the script, I can add a new label with `push`, add the `onClick` for the lagend... but I can't add a function for a specific element for example adding a gradient to a line

```
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: myData,
      borderColor: function(context) {
        const chart = context.chart;
        const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;

        if (!chartArea) {
          return;
        }
        return getGradient(ctx, chartArea);
      },
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function does work but you are missing config, in V3 by default linecharts dont fill anymore so you will need to set `fill` to true, also the dataset background property overrides the one set in the elements part so you will need to rename `backgroundColor` to `pointBackgroundColor` if you want the points to have that color, then it works fine:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    datasets: [{
        data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133],
        label: "Total",
        borderColor: "rgb(62,149,205)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(62,149,205,0.1)",
        fill: true
      },
      {
        data: [70, 90, 44, 60, 83, 90, 100],
        label: "Accepted",
        borderColor: "rgb(60,186,159)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(60,186,159,0.1)",
        fill: true
      },
      {
        data: [10, 21, 60, 44, 17, 21, 17],
        label: "Pending",
        borderColor: "rgb(255,165,0)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(255,165,0,0.1)",
        fill: true
      },
      {
        data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 0, 16],
        label: "Rejected",
        borderColor: "rgb(196,88,80)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(196,88,80,0.1)",
        fill: true
      }
    ]
  },
});

myChart.data.labels.push('June');

myChart.options.plugins.legend.onClick = function(e, legendItem, legend) {
  console.log('legend click');
  console.log(legendItem);
};

myChart.options.elements.line.backgroundColor = function(ctx) {
  return '#000000';
};

myChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="150"></canvas>
```